# SQL Transactions - allow read original data before commit (snapshot?)

Tags: t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2012

I am facing an issue, possibly quite easy to solve, I am just new to advanced transaction settings.

Every 30 minutes I am running an `INSERT` query that is getting latest data from a linked server to my client's server, to a table we can call *ImportTable*. For this I have a simple job that looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
     DELETE FROM  ImportTable

     INSERT INTO ImportTable (columns)
          SELECT (columns)
          FROM QueryGettingResultsFromLinkedServer
COMMIT
```

The thing is, each time the job runs the *ImportTable* is locked for the query run time (2-5 minutes) and nobody can read the records. **I wish the table to be read-accessible all the time, with as little downtime as possible.**

Now, I read that it is possible to allow `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` in the database settings that could probably solve my problem (set to `FALSE` at the moment), but I have never played with different transaction isolation types and as this is not my DB but my client's, I'd rather not alter any database settings if I am not sure if it can break something.

I know I could have an intermediary table that the records are inserted to and then inserted to the final table and that is certainly a possible solution, I was just hoping for something more sophisticated and learning something new in the process.

PS: My client's server & database is fairly new and barely used, so I expect very little impact if I change some settings, but still, I cannot just randomly change various settings for learning purposes.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you have query that take 2-5 minutes then you should be using an intermediary table.  In addition to snapshot.  What is stopping you from installing your own DB for learning?

Comment: @Blam, In the company I work for I have enough space for experimenting with most SQL, but I never needed to alter DB settings and didn't want to install a server on my local machine just for that, possibly a one-time, test. Why would you suggest both intermediary table AND a snapshot? Isn't it overkill? Also, are there any cons to allow snapshot isolation apart from disk space, as the server is using temdb more often? (I hope I understood it correctly)

Comment: Overkill?  Why would you hold any transaction 2-5 minutes if you did not have to?   Why would you not have a test environment?   Really you only have a production environment?

Comment: @Blam, Well, if insert the results of the 2-5min query to an intermediary table and then insert those records to a final table, the actual downtime would be minimal. The query performs a lot of calculations over hundreds of millions of records, but the results are just in a few thousands, which makes inserting almost immediate. And yes, in this case I only have a production environment.

Comment: So then how is an intermediary table overkill?

Comment: I mean overkill having both, the table and the snapshot.

Comment: "I wish the table to be read-accessible all the time".   Why don't you just try something?  I guess for the same reason you cannot be bothered with creating a test environment.

Comment: Now that's you are just being rude. I never "bothered" creating a local testing environment as I have access to several staging environments, that doesn't mean I am going to alter DB properties without seeking a second opinion from someone who knows his stuff on possible impacts of such an alteration, which is what I'm doing. Is this really that bad? Can you please at least tell me why anyone WOULDN'T want to have 'Allow snapshot' enabled?

Comment: If you have access to staging environment then use it.  Anything should be tested prior to going into production.  You are the one that assumed test had to be local.

Comment: I think this a really good question. We have the exact same setup, only that our job is done at night only, and it lasts 10-15 min. During the day, the clients can trigger the job themselves, but then they are aware that the data cannot be accessed. Now for a solution, you could read about the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx  . In any case, I'd suggest you to setup a test environment and experiment with the different settings.

Comment: Hi @SQLPolice, thank you for your comment! As has been suggested, I'll setup a staging DB and try out different transaction settings and approaches to see what's best. Do you plan to implement something like that in your case as well or it's not that vital?

Comment: @MarekStejskal It has currently no priority for us; but we will get an additional external data source, and I plan to redesign the import as a whole, such that it takes place in a more separated area of the database. One additional note for your project: I think if you carry on with the transactions, then the import will take more time and more disk space and more CPU, because the server needs to create the snapshot and hold it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this harder than it needs to be
The problem is the 2-5 minutes that you let be part of a transaction
It is only a few thousand rows - that part takes like a few milliseconds
If you need ImportTable to be available during those few milliseconds then  put it in a SnapShot

```
Delete ImportTableStaging;
INSERT INTO ImportTableStaging(columns)
          SELECT (columns)
          FROM QueryGettingResultsFromLinkedServer;
BEGIN TRAN
     DELETE FROM ImportTable
     INSERT INTO ImportTable (columns) with (tablock)
          SELECT (columns)
          FROM ImportTableStaging
COMMIT
```

If you are worried about concurrent update to ImportTableStaging then use a #temp

Comment: But what if it is 10 million rows? The issue is then that the INSERT is slow, because of the indexes.

Comment: @SQLPolice What??  But it is not 10 million rows.  OP stated a few thousand and I repeated that in my answer.  Even is it was 10 million rows a staging table would be faster.   Where do you get the insert is slow because of indexes?   The result is a few thousand rows.   No amount of indexes is going to make delete and insert of a few thousand rows slow.  And there is no need for indexes on a few thousand rows.

Answer (score 1):

Inserts wont normally block the table ,unless it is escalated to table level.In this case,you are deleting table first and inserting data again,why not insert only updated data?.for the query you are using  transaction level (rsci)snapshot isolation will help you,but you will have an added impact of row version which means sql will store row versions of rows that changed in tempdb.

please see MCM isolation videos of Kimberely tripp for indepth understanding ,also dont forget to test in stage enviornment.

Comment: "why not insert only updated data?" - This may actually be a good idea, but I will still have to identify and delete the rows that no longer match the query results. I found Kimberly's blog post on isolation and the videos on technet, it seems like a source of good info, many thanks!

Comment: This is just plain a bad answer.  If this is a fresh set of data you need the table blocked.   Seeing a partial set of data is typically not a good thing.  Blocked on insert is a good thing.    It is a few thousand rows.